# How to add a “Read more” button to my blog?

Tags: html, read-more

I have an HTML template which I convert to a Wordpress theme, but i can't add a "Read more" button to the home page.

I use the following code in functions.php:

```
function the_content_limit($max_char, $more_link_text = '(more...)', $stripteaser = 0, $more_file = '') {
    $content = get_the_content($more_link_text, $stripteaser, $more_file);
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
    $content = strip_tags($content);

    if (strlen($_GET['p']) > 0) {
        echo "<p>";
        echo $content;
        echo "</p>";
    }
    else if ((strlen($content)>$max_char) && ($espacio = strpos($content, " ", $max_char ))) {
        $content = substr($content, 0, $espacio);
        $content = $content;
        echo "<p>";
        echo $content;
        echo "...";
        echo "</p>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<p>";
        echo $content;
        echo "</p>";
    }
}
```

I also use the following code in index.php:

```
<div class="text_home"><?php the_content_limit(300); ?></div>
```

What can I do to solve my problem?

Comment: In what way can't you add a Read More button?

Comment: Read More button is not appear in home page, i want add "read more" or "more .." to my posts in home page

Comment: What research have you done so far? What have you tried?

Comment: i don't research except this cods (in my post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a basic link to the current post within the loop with

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
```